# javascript - basic onclick event question

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic table populated from an array.

When building the table I have the following inside of a loop:

```
var tdRecord = trRecord.insertCell(trRow.cells.length);
var tdRecordId = dataArray[j][0];
tdRecord.onclick = function() { alert(tdRecordId); }
```

The problem is that alert will only alert the last set tdRecordId in the array. If I click on any of the other td rows they all alert the same number.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Please expand, its unclear what your trying to do.

Comment: Where is the string coming from? How is it related to the table cell?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
(function( id ) {

    tdRecord.onclick = function() {
        alert( id );
    };

}( tdRecordID ));
```

You seem to be running your code inside a loop. In that case, all click handlers will point to the same `tdRecordId` value. If you want to capture the value of the current iteration, you have to use a function wrapper which will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
tdRecord.onclick = function () { alert('123'); };
```

Comment: I think he wanted to pass that argument. Not specify it in the function block.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's data feature: http://jsfiddle.net/zRXS6/.

```
$(function(){
    var number = 1;
    var div1 = $('<div>a</div>');
    div1.data('number', number);
    div1.click(function() {window.alert($(this).data('number'))});
    number = 2;
    var div2 = $('<div>b</div>');
    div2.data('number', number);
    div2.click(function() {window.alert($(this).data('number'))});
    $('body').append(div1).append(div2);
});
```

Comment: You don't want to call the function immediately.

Answer (score -1):

```
tdRecord.onclick = "alert(" + tdRecordId + ")";
```

Set it as a literal, rather then a dynamic. :)

In what you're doing, it will always refer to the variable, rather then the current value.

So as the variable changes, what the function alerts will change.

In this, it actually inserts the value, rather then the variable itself, so it will stay the same instead of changing.